# Change first element style in django template loop divided in if else case

Tags: python, django, templates, loops

I have a loop in my djnago template which is divided in if else case and I need to **change** the first element style in **only** **if** **case**

```
<b><ul>
    {% for i in prosize %}
        {% if i.num_in_stock > 0 %}
            <li ><a  class="order" id="{{i.option1}}" href="javascript:setSize('{{i.option1}}')">{{i.option1}}</a></li>//**i need to chnage the first element style in this case** 
        {% else %}
             <li><a style="background-color:#c2c2c2;color:#000;" href="#myModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal" >{{i.option1}}</a></li>
        {% endif %} 
    {% endfor %}
</ul></b>
```

please suggest how can I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`forloop.first`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for) to check whether current iteration is the first one. In case you wonder, yes, you can use boolean operators like `and` in `if`.

Comment: .red{background-color:black;}
</style>   <b><ul>
      {% for i in prosize %}'
       {% if i.num_in_stock > 0 %}

      <li {% if forloop.first %}class="red"{% endif %}><a  class="order" id="{{i.option1}}" href="javascript:setSize('{{i.option1}}')">{{i.option1}}</a></li>
      {% else %}
      <li><a style="background-color:#c2c2c2;color:#000;" href="#myModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal" >{{i.option1}}</a></li>
      {% endif %} 
        {% endfor %}
      </ul></b>

i have try this but this doesnot help

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods provided by Django for "For loop". You can use below methods.

**forloop.first**    - True if this is the first time through the loop

**forloop.last**     - True if this is the last time through the loop

**forloop.counter**  - The current iteration of the loop (1-indexed)

**forloop.counter0** - The current iteration of the loop (0-indexed)

In your case the code should be like this :

```
<b><ul>
    {% for i in prosize %}
        {% if i.num_in_stock > 0 and forloop.counter == 1 %}
     .....................
```